Shopify GraphQL API - Is it possible to get all company orders over the last 30 days?
I'm looking into fetching all orders for a B2B company from the last 30 days.
After checking out the documentation for both B2B company and orders, I see that it's not possible to use a query on a company order and it's not possible to query for the company specifically when accessing orders directly.
My query currently looks like
  query GetCompanyOrders(
    $query: String
  ) {
      orders(first: 50, query: "created_at:>=2024-07-01 AND company_id:gid://shopify/Company/123456789") {
      nodes {
        id
        displayFulfillmentStatus
        name
        createdAt
        totalPriceSet {
          shopMoney {
            amount
            currencyCode
          }
        }
        lineItems(first: 100) {
          nodes {
            name
            id
            variant {
              sku
            }
            image {
              url
              width
              height
              altText
            }
          }
        }
        shippingAddress {
          formatted
        }
      }
    }
}

It would be great to see if anyone else has run into a similar issue.
Any help would be great. Thanks!

Same here, not possible to use query filters for Company.orders
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-07/objects/Company#connection-orders

That is not an answer but a support of the question.
